# Xcode 11 - framework not found GoogleAppMeasurement

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode11, xcodebuild

I've been facing this weird problem with XCode 11 (Version 11.4.1 (11E503a)) since I started using Cocoapods.

Every morning when I try building my project the "framework not found GoogleAppMeasurement" error appears.

[image]

Also Pods.xcodeproj is marked with red when this happens.

Reopening Xcode doesn't help,

what does help is executing the following 2 commands:

```
pod deintegrate && pod cache clean --all
pod install
```

and it works for a while but next morning it starts from the very beginning. Same error every day.
I also tried changing to "Recursive" some search path values in "project -> build settings" but obviously it didn't help.

I( am almost sure it has nothing to do with that google module as it's just the first module in the Pods.

Podfile contents:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'FitMa' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'

  # Pods for FitMa

end
```

All advice are welcome.

Comment: can you share your podfile ?

Comment: i updated my post with it's content

Comment: unable to reproduce with the above pods. working fine in my workspace.

Comment: @eugene_prg did you found solution for your problem? I have same problem.

Comment: Hi Ramis.. As far as i remember removing StoreKit from package manager helped me.. But not sure if that was the case...

Comment: not sure if this will help anybody but my .gitignore was ignoring GoogleAppMeasurement pods and its links